# Node depth based on pre, post, and in order number in a binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, depth, inorder, preorder, postorder

I have a binary tree where each node has a number that stores which place that node comes in for pre, post, and in order traversal.

This image that I found on google images illustrates what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6phA.gif

The problem I am having trouble figuring out is determining the depth (distance from the root) of a node based on its pre, post, and in order numbers in constant time.

Any help or ideas with this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks.